# Authorize specific nodes - Charlie

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template

I am trying the tutorials "Authorize specific nodes" to authorize access for the third node "Charlie" to the network. I have followed the guide to submit sudo for the Charlie's node and the result is ok, but the node stills not connect to the network. Is there any configuration missing/how can I inspect the issue? Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something may have been wrong when authorising Charlie.
I'd suggest you try to restart the nodes, purging the data:

```
rm -rf /tmp/validator1 (Alice)
rm -rf /tmp/validator2 (Bob)
rm -rf /tmp/validator3 (Charlie)
```

And when go to Developer -> Sudo -> nodeAuthorization -> addWellKnownNode be sure you are adding Charlie's peer identifier decoded to hex: 0x002408011220876a7b4984f98006dc8d666e28b60de307309835d775e7755cc770328cdacf2e

[image]

After it you should see this in the console you are running Charlie's node:

```
2022-09-20 09:52:22  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x6831…07a8), finalized #0 (0x6831…07a8), ⬇ 0.8kiB/s ⬆ 0.8kiB/s  
 2022-09-20 09:52:27  Idle (2 peers), best: #15 (0x66e8…67e1), finalized #13 (0x56b8…3364), ⬇ 2.0kiB/s ⬆ 0.6kiB/s
```

Comment: It works. Thanks Alex.